# Loading keras (tensorflow) model from .h5 file

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, keras

I saved model trained in Keras as .h5 file. 
When trying to load it in distributed setting, I got the error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device
>   to node 'policy/dense_2_b': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/job:ps/task:0' because no devices matching that
>   specification are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0

It seems that somehow variables in .h5 file are assigned to specific device with job "localhost". So when I am trying to load it on parameter server, I get the error.

Could anyone clarify how to address this? I probably should load keras model first without starting servers and then to reload it on parameter server. But details are unclear for me..